# Flickering between Modal Popup Extender windows (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have 3 paging AJAX Modal Popup Extender windows displaying my application's help pages.

I have this script which hides and shows the relevant modal window. Each function is fired from 'Next' and 'Back buttons' in the modal panels.

```
    function Help_Next(sender, args) {

        $find('HelpTable').hide();
        $find('HelpTable2').show();

    }

    function Help_Back(sender, args) {

        $find('HelpTable').show();
        $find('HelpTable2').hide();
    }

    function Help_Last(sender, args) {

        $find('HelpTable3').hide();
        $find('HelpTable').hide();
        $find('HelpTable2').show();

    } 


     </script>
```

The script works fine and allows paging between modal popups. The only issue is that I am experiencing flickering when going back from HelpTable2 to HelpTable. It is prevalent in IE8 but also happens sporadically in Firefox & Chrome. All modal panels share the same grey Modal Background.

```
function Help_Back(sender, args) {

    $find('HelpTable').show();
    $find('HelpTable2').hide();
}
```

Any idea why this occurs?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the order of the show/hide commands in Help_Back, they may be quickly fighting for the spot light which tends to shine pretty dim in IE8